# Can't get Mesh to unwrap properly

Tags: uv

I'm trying to get this chair (the back part) mesh [image]
Unwrap smoothly but it keeps coming out like this
[image]
which causes extreme distortion when i try to put a texture on it.
i'm trying to get it to unwrap smoothly like this
[image]
Can anyone explain to me how i can get my mesh to unwrap like that?

Answer (score 2):

without an blend file i have to guess, but it seems to me, that you missed some uv marks on one end of each of the objects. A cubic object needs to have 3 UV Marks on each of its ends. I made a picture to explain it futher: [image: UV Marks for a cubic Object] If that does not solve the problem, please upload the blend file.
For getting the top and bottom face separated from the object, mark the howl face:[image]